# What would cause numbers to show up as popular keywords?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search, keywords

I'm digging into Google Analytics of a website and I went to check the most popular keywords and they're just numbers (these are just an example, not the actual numbers in the report):
303382264_8055137
1124379684_54841060_368914

These numbers are bringing in thousands of views from search. However, when I search for these numbers there are no search results. The website does get most of its traffic from Pinterest, so I'm curious if this might have something to do with that or something to do with Google Images (as many Google Image results are Pinterest pages.)

My initial thought is that perhaps these are url slugs on the website, but the slugs aren't numerical, they're descriptive (ie. /page_about_zombie_apocalypse)

Actual keywords for the website are barely represented. It's just all these numbers. Thoughts?

Comment: Is this from the keyword data that is imported from Google Search Console or is this from the old referrer reports?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Old referrer reports